# How to create a callback function in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

I have some `asynchronous API calls`. I need to do some work when the calls have finished. I have all my API calls inside a function like that :

```
function startProcess() {
   asyncCall();
}
```

How do i create a `callback function` for the `startProcess()` function , so that i could run some code when the asyncCall has finished?

Comment: The only clean solutions suppose that `asyncCall` itself can accept a callback or post an even somehow when it finishes.

Comment: asyncCall has a callback function. The problem is that through the callback function asyncCall will be called a couple more times with different parameters. So i cant be sure through that callback function when it will finish. If you have time to see what i mean check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965124/how-to-create-use-a-callback-function-with-asynchronous-api-calls . This is my problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the jquery $.when [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Something like this:

```
$.when( startProcess ).done(
    function() { /* do something */ }
);
```

Comment: hmm i get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: I edited the answer, it seems that this could be the correct sintax, let me know.

Comment: is correct but if the call is asynchronous , that doesnt mean that it will wait for that call to finish. Thats what i am trying to accomplish. Thank you very much though